# How to get WorkspaceId in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-desktop

I am new to PowerBI. I am trying to implement "App owns data" i.e. embed reports within my web application. I am following this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-customers

I have downloaded the sample app and I am following the steps. However currently I am stuck at the WorkspaceId. Where can I find the workspaceId? I have looked at all the screens in PowerBI and the associated Azure account but not able to find it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WorkspaceID is the ID of the workspace which you can find from the url of your browser when you select a specific workspace.

It is in this format : https://app.powerbi.com/groups/WorkspaceID/

Comment: Unfortunately, they seem to have changed that link.  I now get "https://app.powerbi.com/groups/me/list/dashboards".  Not exactly helpful...

Comment: "me" -> My workspace. If a report is created in other workspaces other than "My workspace", the workspace ID will still be shown after "groups/"

Answer (score 2):

You can find the workspace ID in the **Admin portal** settings by selecting **Details** next to the workspace name.

[image]

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers?tabs=node-js#workspace-id

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, this one still works in 2023. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a great answer, but it might work for you.

Click on Workspaces on the left menu on the Power BI site, navigate to the App Workspace you want to find the ID of, click on the `...` ellipsis, and choose `Members`.

[image: Menu Screenshot]

When I click on this, it takes me to an Outlook site that has the ID as part of the URL.

[image: Outlook]

For me, the `Files` and `Conversations` options also go to pages where I can extract the ID from the URL.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you were asking but if you want to use the Workspace ID (or any other identifier such as a friendly name, you could add a parameter and when publishing to the workspace, set the value of the parameter to the required value (workspace ID/name).  We are using this to identify DEV/TEST/PROD workspaces within our reports.

Answer (score 0):

A better method is checking the session storage in the browser where you have the workspace. The workspace id is saved as `wid` and under `idTokenClaims` object.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to create a new workspace, you will find that it will have an id